# Change Bar Chart in ASP Net from progress bar to signal the point in the Axis

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have a Bar Chart in ASP Net. By default the bar looks like a progress Bar but I need to make it to look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBtdC.png)

How can I make it look it that?

I tried using a Point Chart however I need it to be horizontal not vertical.

Comment: Hello Classic, do you mean you need it to be vertical (as in the picture) or horizontal? Your last comment seems to contradict your need. Also, you should consider putting up some code for clarity: ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I need it to be like the picture. Sorry about the confusion